# How to use an integer from another class?

Tags: ios

I am making a multiple choice quiz app. In my main class, I have an integer called "points" that is used to display the current points earned in the quiz view. However, I also want to display the points in the view of another class, which tells the user that his answer is correct.

I know that you can do this if one class is a subclass of the other, but can you do it if they are not related?

Comment: Yes, if the property is public. Is the integer in your app delegate?

Comment: No, I declared it in the header file of one of the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to set up `points` as a global variable.  Like so:

1. In your `AppDelegate.h` file insert this line after the `@end`:

   extern int points;
2. In any classes that needed to read/write to points, in the .h files after the `@end`, add this line:

   int points;

Answer (score 0):

I would look into something like Singleton Objects

[This link provides a basic example of simple Singleton Objects,](http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/global-variables-in-iphone-objective-c/) which you could use to share a variable between classes.